# gwt-dev.jar too big to upload to appengine. Can I split a jar file, or... what?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, jar

I recently had to add gwt-dev.jar to my /war/WEB-INF/lib directory, and now when I try to deploy to appengine I get:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Found a jar file too large to upload:
>   "C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\appcfg997121487626565419.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\gwt-dev.jar".  Consider using --enable_jar_splitting.

I'm using the google eclipse plugin, and according to [this issue report](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2552&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Owner%20Summary%20Log%20Component#makechanges) I can't use --enable_jar_splitting.  Ack!

Can I manually split a jar file apart somehow?  I only need a tiny fraction of the thing.  If not, what should I do?

Comment: Why do you need to deploy gwt-dev.jar? You should only need gwt-servlet.jar.

Comment: It has an implementation of a Transformer that the server started wanting after I started using RESTEasy.  I didn't ask too many questions ;)

Comment: You'd be better served by finding the RESTEasy dependency and bundling that individually. You've no idea whether GWT will include it in later releases or introduce incompatibilities.

Comment: I'm using Resteasy and have no such problems. Must be something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract the jar. You'll get a folder structure analogous to that of a java package hierarchy (e.g. com/google/gwt/core). Copy the entire extracted directory structure into war/WEB-INF/lib. Solved.

On linux, you can extract the jar with with `jar -xvf gwt-dev.jar`. On windows, just rename it to a zip and you can extract it like a normal zip file (jar files are actually zip files in disguise)

Any single file larger than 1MB will not upload to the App Engine.

Comment: My bad, you're right. It used to be 1MB before your christmas present ;-)

Comment: WRONG - do not accept this as the correct answer. The answer is generally correct but the context is wrong. As others noted `gwt-dev.jar` should not be uploaded to the server as it's only needed at compile-time.

Comment: He didn't ask whether he should deploy it, he asked how t deploy it

Comment: After posting, I did the right thing and found an implementation of the class I needed elsewhere, but I think this is a correct answer to the question I asked.  Thanks for the help and advice!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Windows command line:

```
\path\to\appcfg.cmd --enable_jar_splitting update path\to\war
```

See how to create a deploy shortcut [here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1664#c17).

Answer (score 1):

`gwt-user` should not be in the resulting jar, as its dependency scope is `provided`. Or at least it should be. The [instructions from David Chandler, part of the GWT team](http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2011/03/08/gwt-maven-gae-gotcha/) suggest that the `maven-clean-plugin` should be used to remove the jar from the resulting WAR file.

Answer (score 1):

@Robert is right, you should just delete `gwt-user.jar` prior to uploading. If you really have a big jar, use `--enable_jar_splitting` as proposed by @systempuntoout. If you're using Maven, the equivalent of `--enable_jar_splitting` is available with the [maven-gae-plugin](http://www.kindleit.net/maven_gae_plugin/maven-gae-plugin/deploy-mojo.html#splitJars) via the `splitJars` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error (ironically for the same reason, gwt-dev.jar added to WEB-INF/lib to appease dependencies). In the end I was able to get the app to start AND upload to app engine by ditching gwt-dev.jar and adding xalan.jar to the WEB-INF/lib.

I think Peter Knego is right, it's better _not_to upload the gwt-dev.jar