# Problem running a GWT 2.4 App on Tomcat

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

I have a problem running my gwt2.4rc1 application in a tomcat. The problem occurs when I try to make a requestfactory call. Then I get the exception at the bottom.

When I run GWT in development mode everything works fine. The gwt-dev. jar is in the lib folder of my webapp. I am using maven for dependency management. Could there be a problem with my configuration? I already had the error with gwt2.4 beta. If there are any other information required to solve this problem I am glad to provide them.

Regards,
Arne

SEVERE: Unexpected error
com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.UnexpectedException: Unexpected checked exception
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator.die(ServiceLayerDecorator.java:216)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerCache.getOrCache(ServiceLayerCache.java:242)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerCache.resolveRequestFactory(ServiceLayerCache.java:198)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.process(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:201)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.process(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:125)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet.doPost(RequestFactoryServlet.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:261)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:175)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:62)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:162)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:203)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:558)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:379)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:242)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:259)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:281)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/dev/util/StringKey
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2804)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1639)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1517)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryInterfaceValidator.validateProxy(RequestFactoryInterfaceValidator.java:1594)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryInterfaceValidator.validateEntityProxy(RequestFactoryInterfaceValidator.java:828)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryInterfaceValidator.maybeCheckProxyType(RequestFactoryInterfaceValidator.java:1540)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryInterfaceValidator.getDomainType(RequestFactoryInterfaceValidator.java:1374)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryInterfaceValidator.createDomainMethod(RequestFactoryInterfaceValidator.java:1192)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryInterfaceValidator.checkClientMethodInDomain(RequestFactoryInterfaceValidator.java:1079)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryInterfaceValidator.validateRequestContext(RequestFactoryInterfaceValidator.java:909)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryInterfaceValidator.validateRequestFactory(RequestFactoryInterfaceValidator.java:964)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ResolverServiceLayer.resolveRequestFactory(ResolverServiceLayer.java:187)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator.resolveRequestFactory(ServiceLayerDecorator.java:172)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator.resolveRequestFactory(ServiceLayerDecorator.java:172)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator.resolveRequestFactory(ServiceLayerDecorator.java:172)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator.resolveRequestFactory(ServiceLayerDecorator.java:172)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerCache.getOrCache(ServiceLayerCache.java:233)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.dev.util.StringKey
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1672)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1517)
    ... 57 more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [a fix for this](http://gwt-code-reviews.appspot.com/1479802/) on its way over from RC to trunk. In the mean time, remove gwt-servlet from your dependencies and use requestfactory-servlet.jar instead.

Comment: thanks for the answer! unfortunately I use gin in my project which adds a dependency on gwt-servlet-2.2 . When I remove my gwt-servlet-jar I get another error (posted here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649483/problems-with-gwt-2-4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649483/problems-with-gwt-2-4) I guess this is because I haven't figured out how to add a dependency on a library in my own repository to gwt-maven-plugin. Can you provide any information when this fix is submitted to svn repository?

Comment: FYI: committed and merged to the 2.4 release branch: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/detail?r=10453

Answer (score 0):

I've always understood gwt-dev.jar to be the compiler and other development tools. If you believe that, there should be no dependency on it from your own code, and there is no reason for it to be in the WEB-INF/lib folder of your war file.

I see from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477977/gwt-dev-jar-too-big-to-upload-to-appengine-can-i-split-a-jar-file-or-what) that at least one other contributer to SO feels the same way, but the belief doesn't appear to be universal.

I'll update this answer if I can find anything one way or the other in the GWT docs.

**Update:**
The closest thing I could find was [Organize Projects](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideDirectoriesPackageConventions) which shows gwt-dev as a referenced library not present in WEB-INF/lib. I can't find anything official that says either that you can or can't deploy it to your web server. In an old book *GWT In Action* (Hanson, 2007), page 551 says

> You should never deploy the gwt-user.jar and gwt-dev.jar files to your server, 
>   because they will interfere with your server; these JAR files contain their own 
>   Tomcat server code, which is used when you're testing in hosted mode.

This is clearly out of date, since hosted mode isn't called that anymore and uses an embedded Jetty server rather than Tomcat, but that's the basis for my belief.

Comment: thanks for these information! I will try to get rid of these dependencies even though this was not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I made it working :) 
I used the gwt version compiled from here:
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/#svn%2Freleases%2F2.4

I did put gwt-servlet.jar and requestfactory-servlet.jar as dependencies in my project. The problem in the other thread occured because I used my own group-id for the compiled jars, so these were not used by gin and the gwt-maven-plugin. No everything works fine :)

Thanks for the help though!!